# Server side and client side validation possible

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, validation

in my requirement, i am require to use 1 editor and requiredfieldvalidator doesn't work on this Editor control. So i am validating this control through javascript and rest of the asp.net control through asp controls validator on a single click of a button.

I am trying to implement server side validation through aspnet server side control and client side validation through javascript.
i have two textbox control and one submit button as follows :

```
<div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvTxt1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"
            ControlToValidate="Txt1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" Text="Submit" 
        OnClientClick=" return ss();"  />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div> 



 <script src="JS/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ss() {
            var script = $("#<%=Txt2.ClientID %>").val();
            if (script == "") {
                alert(1);
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "dd";
    }
    protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "ss";
    }
```

but both the validation doesn't work.
problem is, when the second textbox contains the Text. The page postback and runs it event even if the first Textbox doesn't contain its text.
 Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Where is `ss()` defined and what does it contain?

Comment: why dont u use requiredfield validator for both textboxes...i see no reason why it wont work.

Answer (score 2):

I am presenting the solution for your query.
You have to just enable all server validation again in else condition of clientside validation function.

```
function ss() 
{
var script = $("#<%=Txt2.ClientID %>").val();
if (script == "") 
{
    alert(1);
    Page_ClientValidate();
    return false;
}
else 
{
    Page_ClientValidate();
}
}
```

OR

just change the button click as :

protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            Label1.Text = "ss";
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Why not 2 RequiredFieldValidators, one for each TextBox?

```
<div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvTxt1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"
            ControlToValidate="Txt1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvTxt2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"
            ControlToValidate="Txt2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" Text="Submit" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Or, if you REALLY want to use custom validation, use `CustomValidator`. Here is example for both client and server side validation:

```
<div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvTxt1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"
            ControlToValidate="Txt1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"
           ControlToValidate="Txt2"
           ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate"
           OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
           ErrorMessage="*"
           ForeColor="Red"
           runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" Text="Submit" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div> 

<script language="javascript"> 
   function ClientValidate(source, arguments)
   {
        if (arguments.Value == "" ){
            arguments.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            arguments.IsValid = false;
        }
   }
</script>

<script runat="server">
    void ServerValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
      return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Value);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ValidationGroup` to tie your controls with you submit button
and ensure that you use `CauseValidation` attribute on Button equal `True`

**EDIT**

```
document.getElementById('<%=txt2.ClientID%>').value;
```

try this 
may help

Comment: Sir, i have tried doing what you have stated above and i have updated my final issue.

Comment: well, you're using a master page here ? i mean you are sure that you are locating your textbox correctly ?

Comment: No sir.......... in my requirement, i am require to use 1 editor and requiredfieldvalidator doesn't work on this Editor control. So i am validating this control through javascript and rest of the asp.net control through asp controls validator on a single click of a button.